# What is the meaning of org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, badsqlgrammarexception

If you're working on Spring boot application, there are high chances that you will use hibernate to map java objects to relational database. In such a case, JPA entities, which are pre-defined POJOs that can be stored in a database, are passed to a Spring-DAO which then uses hibernate to store the data.

Therefore, all the sql queries are handled by hibernate which eliminates the chances of getting syntax errors in sql statements.

Yet, I recently got `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement` in my spring boot application, and I'm curious to know that,

1. What does `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement` actually mean? And,
2. What are the possible reasons which can raise this exception(is it only related to SQL syntax or can it point to some other problem in the code)?

Comment: This could be due to any number of problems. Table doesn't exist in database, illegal names, etc.